# Trying to get the greatest value from a customer on a given day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I need to do: if a customer makes more than one transaction in a day, I need to display the greatest value (and ignore any other values).

The query is pretty big, but the code I inserted below is the focus of the issue. I’m not getting the results I need. The subselect ideally should be reducing the number of rows the query generates since I don’t need all the transactions, just the greatest one, however my code isn’t cutting it. I’m getting the exact same number of rows with or without the subselect.

*Note: I don’t actually have a t.* in the actual query, there’s just a dozen or so other fields being pulled in. I added the t.* just to simplify the code example.*

```
SELECT
t.*,
(SELECT TOP (1)
t1.CustomerGUID
t1.Value
t1.Date
FROM #temp t1
WHERE t1.CustomerGUID = t.CustomerGUID
AND t1.Date = t.Date
ORDER BY t1.Value DESC) AS “Value”
FROM #temp t
```

Is there an obvious flaw in my code or is there a better way to achieve the result of getting the greatest **value** transaction per **day** per **customer**?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you may want to do as follows:

```
SELECT
       t1.CustomerGUID,
       t1.Date,
       MAX(t1.Value) AS Value
  FROM #temp t1
 GROUP BY 
       t1.CustomerGUID,
       t1.Date
```

Comment: I’m going to try this out. I tried using the MAX function but foolishly didn’t use a GROUP BY which explains why it was causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` as shown below.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerGUID ORDER BY Date Desc) AS SrNo FROM <YourTable>
)
  <YourTable>
WHERE
  SrNo = 1
```

Sample data will be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I specify the “Value” field in the subselect or is it ok to just use it in the *?

Comment: You can use both either specific column name or *.

Comment: I couldn't get this one to work, but I switched around some of the fields and finally got it to sequence the values in order, based on the same date and same customer:                                                                         `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CustomerGUID, t.Date ORDER BY t.Value DESC)`

Comment: @DPool34 Ya it was just an idea to get the latest data and definitely you need to do some modification as per your business logic and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this window function:

```
MAX(value) OVER(PARTITION BY date,customer ORDER BY value DESC)
```

Its faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Probably many other ways to do it, but this one is simple and works

```
select t.* 
from (
    select
         convert(varchar(8), r.date,112) one_day
        ,max(r.Value) max_sale
    from #temp r
    group by convert(varchar(8), r.date,112)
) e
inner join #temp t on t.value = e.max_sale and convert(varchar(8), t.date,112) = e.one_day
```

if you have 2 people who spend the exact same amount that's also max, you'll get 2 records for that day.

the `convert(varchar(8), r.date,112)` will perform as desired on date, datetime and datetime2 data types. If you're date is a varchar,char,nchar or nvarchar you'll want to examine the data to find out if you `left(t.date,10) or left(t.date,8)` it.

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood your requirement correctly you have stated"greatest value transaction per day per customer". That suggests to me you don't want 1 row per customer in the output but a row per day per customer.

To achieve this you can group on the day like this

```
Select t.customerid, datepart(day,t.date) as Daydate, 
max(t.value) as value from #temp t group by 
t.customerid,  datepart(day,t.date);
```